# Is there a way to remap all foreign key references for a given ID to another ID in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Lets say, there is a table with a simple numeric ID column with values 1 and 2. And there are few dozens of other tables, that have rows with ID = 1 referenced in their foreign keys. Is there any way to cascade update all those references to 2 without generating updates for all the referencing tables?

UPDATE to clarify it a bit further.

We got a dictionary table like that, called `CompanyTypes`:

```
ID | Name
---------
1  | Bar
2  | Restaurant
```

And we have a bunch of tables referencing that dictionary in their FKs. For simplicity, lets go with one named `Companies`:

```
ID | Name       | Type
----------------------
1  | Cool bar   | 1
2  | Not a bar  | 2
```

And now there came an administrative decision that we no longer need bars as a distinct company type, and now all the bars have to be remapped to be restaurants *without altering the db schema* (so I can not add mapping table or something like that). Yes, I can write a query to generate queries to update each table individually (`UPDATE Companies SET Type = 2 WHERE Type = 1` and so on), but is there any way to trick the db engine into doing it for me?

Comment: Why not just update the Name in Company_Types, leaving the id and hence the FKs unchanged.

Comment: @Belayer because I need to actually merge them to be one entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an anonymous code block to iterate over [all tables that have a foreign key related to](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/list-all-tables-refrenced-by-specific-table) `CompanyTypes` and concatenate the table name with an `UPDATE` statement:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT DISTINCT fk_tco.table_name as fk_table_name
               FROM information_schema.referential_constraints rco
               JOIN information_schema.table_constraints fk_tco ON
                  rco.constraint_name = fk_tco.constraint_name AND
                  rco.constraint_schema = fk_tco.table_schema
               JOIN information_schema.table_constraints pk_tco ON
                  rco.unique_constraint_name = pk_tco.constraint_name AND
                  rco.unique_constraint_schema = pk_tco.table_schema
               WHERE pk_tco.table_name = 'companytypes' 
               ORDER BY fk_table_name 
    LOOP
      EXECUTE format('UPDATE %s SET Type = 2 WHERE Type = 1',row.fk_table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=be85ae031babb5e2ba10c037371e1a59)

Comment: That is not really what I was asking about. I'm not looking for the way to update the referenced row's ID, I'm looking for the way to redirect references to another already existing row.

Comment: @Xandrmoro ok, sorry .. it wasn't clear your question. Perhaps you could add the ddl statements of your tables and the expected result? pseudo-code is fine. Preferably, put your data sample in a fiddle

Comment: It is pretty much what I ended up doing (mine is a bit more complex tho, because column name can vary too), so I guess there is no better way

Comment: @Xandrmoro you could also get the column name from the `information_schema`. The query would have to be slightly updated.